# Calling mobile site from desktop at certain browser width?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, webforms, responsive-design

I need to have my website scale down to the mobile site after a certain width. Ex. if it scales down to < 900px it changes to the mobile site and when it scales back up to the desktop version. I don't mind if it has to reload to either site. I've tried searching for a while now and it's always about using the Regex code and browser detection to set what the page is. I need it to switch based off of browser size.
I'm using asp.net and VS2013 as my IDE. I'm not well versed in PHP, so if this could be answered using asp,html,css, or c# code directly I would be appreciative.

I am currently using this from addmobilebrowser.com

```
string checkDestopStatus = Request["version"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(checkDestopStatus))
        {
            String u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            bool mobileUser = false;

            Regex b = new Regex("android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|android|ipad|playbook|silk|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Regex v = new Regex("1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
            if (u.Length > 4)
            {
                if (b.IsMatch(u) | v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4)))
                {
                    mobileUser = true;
                }
            }

            if (mobileUser)
            {
                //  mobileSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MobileSiteURL"];
                Response.Redirect("/mobile/" + Request.Path );
            }
        }
        else
        {


        }
```

I am currently using bootstrap with CSS media queries. The question here is asking how to force the switch manually either server side or client side. without having to rewrite my existing media queries.

Comment: You can do it with css like this `@media only screen and (max-width: 900px)`

Comment: Google "Responsive Design".  That's the terminology for that behavior.  You should get all the info you need.

Comment: C# and PHP and ASP are server side. No need to ask for a solution using that. This can be solved with client side technology, particularly CSS. As an easy to get started with responsive web site, check out [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) and their examples.

Comment: Get the screen resolution passed to the server side. Then if it's outside your limits, perform redirect. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520296/Getting-Available-Resolution-from-Server-Code-in-A) for passing the resolution to the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a framework like  [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Or you can use CSS3 Media Queries here is an example [CSS3 media queries](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: Not really a fix to my problem as I asked, But If I had restarted the entire project this would have been optimal.